# Is $Pr(A \cap C) = Pr(B \cap C)$ given that $Pr(A) = Pr(B)$?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $Pr(A) = Pr(B)$. For any event $C$, is it hold that $Pr(A \cap C) = Pr(B \cap C)$? When $A$ and $C$ are independent and $B$ and $C$ are independent the proof is easy but, is it hold in the general case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this diagram answer your question?

[image]

Comment: Of course! I was trying it with coin tosses too, but this is way more visual. Thank you!